# I am getting a segementation Error in pointer when i try to print a string using char * it,why?

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I am trying to store strings using
`char *p,*s;`:

```
scanf("%s", p);
scanf("%s", s);
printf("%s\n", p);
```

It works so far but when I call `printf` on `s` it's giving me a segmentation error.
I don't know why.  Can anyone explain?  I am using linux and gcc.

Comment: Have you allocated any memory space for `p` and `s`?

Comment: I'm rather surprised the `scanf`s didn't cause the crash.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, p and s are **uninitialized pointers**; they don't point to any valid memory. You must allocate memory for them to point to. See the example below.

```
char* p = malloc(10); // allocate 10 bytes and point p to them
char* s = malloc(10); // allocate 10 bytes and point s to them
scanf("%s", p);
scanf("%s", s);
printf("%s\n", p);

// free the memory when you don't need it anymore
free(p);
free(s);
```

If the data you expect to put into p and s is larger than 10 bytes, allocate more.

Comment: Well, we don't know that they're actually `NULL`.  Their values are indeterminate.  But you're right.  They don't point to any valid memory.

Comment: And remember that C strings are null-terminated: they end in a byte set to `'\0'` to indicate their end. If your string is 10 characters long, you actually need to allocate 11 bytes.

Comment: I thought that if i was able  to use *p to store string  without allocating , so with *s but it was not working with *s the second pointer. 
anyway thank for info.